# Pandas Jupyter - "day is out of range for month:" Trying to convert 'Order Date' to DataTime Object in Python

Tags: python, pandas

i got this error :  `ParserError: day is out of range for month: 2/29/2021  12:20:00 PM`

i tried to look at the solutions here but nothing is correct my ERROR, why i cant convert it successfuly ? this is my template of Order Date: `2/29/2021  12:20:00 PM`

thats my code:

`    # Add hour column

```
 all_data['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['Order Date']).dt.hour
 all_data['Minute'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['Order Date']).dt.minute
 all_data['Count'] = 1
 all_data.head()   `
```

tried first also : `all_data['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['Order Date'])`

Comment: Problem is `2/29/2021` not exist, so need `pd.to_datetime(all_data['Order Date'], errors='coerce')` for `NaT` for this wrong datetime.

Comment: @jezrael Oh man youre the best .  How may i can cotact you please ?

Comment: Hmm, some problem with data?

Comment: @jezrael Yeah , working on csv with pandas. create a project... you have maybe discord ?

Comment: Sorry, a bit busy.